# XCOPY files from directory with Batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

In a folder I have a batch file and another folder name Themes.

I would like to be able to share this with others so looking to make the source directory independent of the location of the parent.

```
XCOPY /E/Y "\Themes\*.thmx" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\"
```

Running the batch file returns "File not found - *.thmx"

Comment: See `call /?`. `"%~dp0Themes\*.thmx"`. `%0` is the batchfile itself.

Comment: I recommend to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~dp0Themes\*.thmx" "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" /C /I /Q /Y >nul`. Run in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) `xcopy /?` for help on the options and see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). `%~dp0` expands to full path of currently executed batch file which ends always with a backslash.

Comment: See https://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-2-variables.html